# No page views and unique visits required to get Google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

I wanted to know the average unique visits to get Google AdSense.

Answer (score 1):

There is no number of page views required to be eligible for AdSense. In fact, Google won't know how many page views you get. What matters is that your site meets their [quality guidelines and policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en).

Comment: When i asked in other fourms about rejection of website in google adsense the said </br>
Since there are many technical websites google at present not accepting Techinical blogs for adsense</br>

is that true